# Why $match with $eq works very slow, but with $neq very fast?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Look at the query:

```
db.pmusers.aggregate(
    {
        $unwind: '$preferableUsersIds'
    },
    {
        $project: {
            cmp_value: {$cmp:['$id', '$preferableUsersIds']},
            id:1
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            cmp_value: {$ne: 0}
        }
    }
)
```

This works very quickly.

but if replace

```
$match: {
                cmp_value: {$ne: 0}
        }
```

with

```
   $match: {
                cmp_value: {$eq: 0}
           }
```

Can you explain this behaviour?

### P.S.

According Neil Lunn advice I have wrote the following:

```
db.pmusers.aggregate(
    {
        $unwind: '$preferableUsersIds'
    },
    {
        $redact:{
            $cond:[
                    {
                        $eq : [
                            {$cmp:['$id', '$preferableUsersIds']},
                            0
                        ]
                    },
                    '$$DESCEND',
                    '$$PRUNE'
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            id:1
        }
    }
)
```

It works approximately twice faster.

Comment: Can you give the source of the benchmark?

Comment: This is [documented and expected](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/). *"The inequality operator $ne is not very selective since it often matches a large portion of the index. As a result, in many cases, a $ne query with an index may perform no better than a $ne query that must scan all documents in a collection. See also [Query Selectivity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#read-operations-query-selectivity)."* In brief, the logic dictates that more things match the "negative" than a "positive". Or when the "reverse" case is true, then faster

Comment: You also need to acquaint yourself with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/), since running `$project` followed by `$match` effectively runs through the data **twice**, which is not very performant. `$redact` is doing the same thing in **one** pass.

Comment: @lilezek I just run this in mongo shell. I see difference without benchmark

Comment: @Neil Lunn, thanks I will try to learn $redact

Comment: @Neil Lunn I have updated topic. Do you think current solution is ok?